# Create the controls dynamically using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, advanced-search

I am new to angularjs, can anyone help me to create the dynamic controls for advance search using angular js.

like 
We have Advance search button after click on this some basic filter controls should load and after click on + or - button dymanicaaly load another filter controls with "And" / "OR" option.

We need something like below screenshot.
Datatype dropdown and select date option will be present for default search. if person clicks on advance search filter option will come on screen. 
then we need to add one dropdown as dynamic control and if drop down menu item is suitable to textbox then start with, end with should come, if item suitable for date then datepicker control should come . After that also user can add more search conditions by clicking on plus or minus button.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the controller have an array containing your filter options:

```
$scope.filters = []
```

Add a click on Advanced Search:

```
$scope.onAdvancedSearchClick = function() {
    $scope.advancedSearch = true;
    $scope.onClickPlus(); // add initial item
}

$scope.onClickPlus = function() {
    $scope.filters.push({text: 'some text', type: 'AND'});
}

$scope.onClickMinus = function() {
    $scope.filters.pop();
}
```

Then on your view have ng-repeat that loops over the filters array and creates a text input and "and/or" buttton for each one.

I am not sure if you want and/or per row or top level control.

Comment: Thanks mbdev for reply.  Could you please suggest more, i have added a screenshot too.